# JSP with JSTL does not print variables

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags, ejb-2.x

I have problem with JSTL taglib variable printing.

My JSP file:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="/WEB-INF/c.tld"%>
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="/WEB-INF/fn.tld" %>
....
<%
    String val1 = "";
    Object val = RequestUtils.lookup(pageContext, "Form", Names.Val.full(), null);
    if (val != null) {
      val1= ResponseUtils.filter(val.toString());
    }
System.out.println(val1); // (correct)
%>

<c:out value="${val1}" />
<c:out value="<%=val1 %>" />
<c:set var="some" value="<%=val1 %>" />
<c:out value="${some}" />
...
```

Output:

- ${val1} (incorrect)
- Test (correct)
- ${some} (incorrect)

What is wrong? Please help!

Comment: could not understand your requirement

Comment: How can I use Java variable in JSTL context...?

Comment: Have you tried pageContext.setAttribute("val1",val1); ?

Comment: request.setAttribute or pageContext.setAttribute does not working... Maybe there is another way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I found solution:

```
<%@page isELIgnored="false"%>
```

Comment: Thanks man. You saved the day. It sucks to maintain old ass software.